# Why does French use diminutive suffixes differently from other Romance languages?

Tags: romance-languages, gender, diminutive

I'm a native French speaker, and I noticed that for a lot of masculine objects, we use the suffix `-ette` to designate a smaller version of it, which turns it into a feminine word. Here are a few examples:

```
 Petit balai --> Balayette
 Petit camion --> Camionnette
 Petite fourche --> Fourchette
 etc.
```

The `-ette` suffix [(apparently) originates](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ette) from the Latin suffix `-itta`.

Versions of it can be found in other Latin languages, such as the Spanish `-ito` and `-ita`, or the Italian `-etto` and `-etta`, which seem to be used accordingly with the gender of the word they are attached to. In French, we do have the masculine suffix `-et`, but it is not used consistently with masculine words.

Interestingly, diminutive suffixes can also originate [from Latin `inus`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-inus#Latin) (like the Portuguese `-inho` and `-inha`, and the Italian `-ino` and `-ina`), but in French it gave birth to the suffix `-in`, which I believe is used for different purposes.

**How come French doesn't consistently use "-et" for masculine words, and "-ette" for feminine words?** Where in time did it become different from other Romance languages (if it really is)?

Comment: I think there are many examples where diminutives are used inconsistently in Italian as well. For example the diminutive of *camion* (m) is *camionetta* (f) and of *tasca* (f) is *taschino* (m). So it's not clear to me why you are singling French in this.

Comment: I may be wrong in singling French. I'm doing so because that's the language I'm the most comfortable with, and I don't have enough knowledge in Italian, Spanish or other Romance languages to easily find examples. However, I am interested in why diminutives are used inconsistently with genders, whatever the language. Do you think I should turn my question into a more general one? Cheers!

Comment: I am not an expert in the history of the French language, but maybe it is a German substrate/adstrate effect: German has one common gender (neuter in the German case) for all diminutives.

Comment: An obvious characteristic of French vs the other Romance languages is that the loss or neutralisation of final vowels has led to far less obvious morphological distinction between _m_ and _f_ forms. Woud you expect _-ittu_  to have a different result in French from _-itta_?

Comment: @ColinFine yes, -ittum gives the (relatively rare) masculine -et ending, whilst -itta gives the (common) feminine -ette ending

Comment: @ColinFine -ittu yielded French -et /ɛ/, while -itta became -ette /ɛt(ə)/. -et isn't productive anymore, while -ette still is, which might be what precipitated the question from the OP, since words in -ette feel a lot more like a root+a suffix than words in -et do.

Comment: I'll add that the reverse phenomenon (feminine words suffixed by -et) does happen: la cabine -> le cabinet, la brique -> le briquet, la pistole -> le pistolet, la feuille -> le feuillet, la mule -> le mulet, la cervelle -> le cervelet. Most of those don't feel like diminutives anymore though.